# HTML: Play sounds on mouse hover or click

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio

On my site I want to play tick/click like sounds on mouse over (hover) or on mouse clicks. Can this be achieved?

I can do this in flash, but I want to avoid flash.

Comment: Please be sure to have a very easy option to disable the feature. There are those of us who get no joy out of a site making noise at us. :-)

Comment: this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342803/audio-on-mouseover

Comment: If you want to play a sound on-click, then see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025223/play-sound-on-click

Answer (score 2):

See here for all the options that you have if you dont want flash 
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm

Javascript cannot play audio so one of the above is the only way out.

See 3 & 4 in above link and you can trigger it probably on mouse over with javascript.

OR DHTML to play sound http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can play audio with  tag or object or embed. This is the best way like below. You can control audio tag with javascript.

You can control audio by clicking these button:

Play

Stop

And you must put this script to

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    //audioElement.load()
    $.get();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    }, true);




    $('.play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
    });


    $('.pause').click(function() {
    audioElement.pause();
    });

     });
```

But for Chrome you cant use .play() and .pause(). You must use .Play() and .Stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can control an HTML5 `<audio>` element from JavaScript.

This won’t work in IE 8 and below (not sure about 9) though, nor in older versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.