# play sound on click

Tags: javascript, audio

i have asked this question in a couple of places, but have yet to find or receive an answer. i am a code newbie, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

i am using in-page javascript on some of my pages to play a sound on clicking an image which loops a backing track to practise scales / lead guitar to.

here's the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"true\" />";
}
</script>
<span id="dummy"></span>
```

and here's how i'm calling it for each image / mp3:

```
<p><a title="Play file" href="#" onclick="playSound('mp3 url');"><img title="Play" src="play button url" alt="Play" width="48" height="48" /></a>  Blues in <strong>C</strong> : backing for lead melody. Chords: C,F, G</p>
```

my first question - the track isn't looping - is there something wrong with the script?

my second question - how do i extend the function so that on clicking the png to play the file it is swapped for another - stop button - which stops the loop when clicked.

many thanks, jan

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Embedding sounds into web pages is a really tricky business and getting a solution that will work across all browsers and on mobile devices is a real challenge.

Fortunately there are libraries that you can use to make the embedding, playing, looping, switching of mp3s much, much easier.

I'd recommend looking into [Soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), before you get too much further into this project to see if it could save you a lot of coding time, effort and frustration!

Comment: hi. thank you very much for the prompt response - i've had this question festering on a number of forums for several weeks and had no responses. do you know whether soundmanager will allow me to keep my styling - see http://dev.budestrings.co.uk/grade-3/ because i've worked really hard to get this looking right. many thanks, jan

Comment: Yes, Soundmanager just takes care of the business of playing sounds - the look and feel of your page is up to you.

Comment: Which JavaScript files will I need to include on a web page in order to use SoundManager2?