# jQuery: stop audio on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, audio

I'm using the following script to play a sound when someone hovers a div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var birdaudio = birdhover.find('audio')[0];    

 $('.sound').mouseenter(function(){ birdaudio.play(); });
 $('.sound').mouseleave(function(){ birdaudio.stop(); });
});
```

It actually works, but the audio keeps on playing till the end of the sound, even when not hovering anymore. Is there something I could to do to prevent that? I wan't that the audio stops whenever you 'mouseleave' the div.

Hoping for help!

Comment: Here's something related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342803/audio-on-mouseover

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `.stop()` for HTML5 media elements. You must call `pause()` on the element instead.

In order to fully replicate the functionality of a stop (both stop the audio and set it's playback position to the very beginning), you would then follow your `pause()` call with `birdaudio.currentTime = 0`.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for! Thanks, worked like a charm.