# jQuery Sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am using the [jQuery Sound Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound) to create some sound effects on my site yet I cannot get it to play. I recieve this message:

```
settings.events.error(null, {msg: "You have not yet bound the sound player to 
this element"});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(".sound1").sound({swf: url});
 $j(".sound1").load(url);
 $j(".sound1").play();
 $j(".sound1").pause();
 $j(".sound1").stop();
 $j(".sound1").volume(0-100);
 $j('.sound1').mouseover(function() {
 $j(".sound1").play('/messages4u/2011/images/october/sound1.mp3');
});
</script>
```

I am not sure if everything is needed in the code yet I am not that good at JS and need some help! Do I need to specify the URLs? If so to what?

Comment: Unrelated: in a general sense you might want to avoid reselecting everytime: `$j('...').method1().method2() or var elem = $j(...); elem.method1(); elem.method2()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know JS-with-FLASH APIs at all but as a very basic observation, if the page has an SWF component to load, it looks like this JS is firing before it has loaded. You will need to delegate the event or use a callback if there's one available.

Or even more basic: *is* there the flash component included on the page? That project seems abandoned (no official homepage when I went looking for the API); did they include it with the download you used?

Since the error message says "on this element", is it possible that the Flash component isn't listening for an element with the class "sound1"? Is there in fact an element with that class on the page?

I have to admit, I probably shouldn't have tried answering with so many unknowns. The plugin is rather old and unmaintained, so there's no demo page that I could find, and I'm loathe to install the whole thing. Do you have a live link?

Comment: It had 2 flash files included those are uploaded yet I assumed the JS called them. Hmm

Comment: I don't know if loading Flash will "block" the page load. They might still be loading in the background when the JS is attempted. Or if it IS a blocking call, maybe they're simply in the wrong order in the head? Another suggestion in my main response as well.

Comment: Lynda, I don't totally understand how the Flash component works, but this much is clear: the jQuery is set to trigger several functions (including "play") on an element. In this post's code, that element has the class "sound1". In your sample, it has the ID "sound". In your test page, there is NO element with the ID "sound", which is where the error is coming from. I'm not sure what the methodology is for choosing the selector "#sound", or how the Flash component binds to "#sound", but without that element there, the JavaScript will certainly fail out.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have changed the ID to sound across the board but when I look I see the first error says URL not defined I load the SWF player  then it has LOAD: URL  and I have no clue what to put there, I have tried the sound file, the actionscript file, and the SWF file. Any ideas? Also do you have a solution that will play audio on mouseover? I have found multiple but either they do not work at all. They work only in IE 9+ and other browsers. I need a solution that works in IE 8+ and other browsers. This is very frustrating so far. The life of cross browser compatibility...

Comment: I would think the LOAD: URL should be the actual URL that has the sound you want to play. To test, just plunk the URL into the browser address bar and it should try to download (not play) the sound.