# Play sound on menu items on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How can I go about making a sound clip play when an element is hovered over?

I'm using the latest Wordpress, and the parent theme I am using gives me an option to paste scripts which it will embed to the `<head>` section.

Is there a script which I can just add to my `<head>` that will play the sound when the cursor moves over my menu item class `.menu li`?

I spent several hours trying to figure this out the other day with no avail. I've done this before in a simple HTML website:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
</head>

<li><a href="index.html" onmouseover="playSound('lib/hover.mp3');" onclick="playSound('lib/click.mp3');"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

Not sure how to deploy this on Wordpress though.

Comment: What about HTML5 audio tag? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Comment: 2 questions: Are you on WordPress.com or are you self-hosting a WordPress.org site? When you say "the latest WordPress theme" do you mean WP 3.4.2, Twenty Eleven?

Comment: Or this one: http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Comment: this is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342803/audio-on-mouseover